# VSTS incident management?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, servicenow

Does Microsoft contain a feature within VSTS which follows the reported bugs from client side? Bear in mind that there is SLA with response time.

Right now I am using Service Now, but it does not make sense having to track the same bug in two places...

Comment: TFS doesn't have an SLA component. Tracking bugs is pretty much possible, Using custom fields to track SLA related information works but it's far from ideal.

Comment: With some work it's possibel to combine ServiceNow and VSTS: https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/IntegratingServiceNowWithVstsReleaseManagementUsingDeploymentGate

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new work item type and name it as 'incident' for tracking incidents. Here is a link to get you started:-

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404855(VS.80).aspx

Use queries and analytics to fetch SLA/SLI in PowerBI Dashboard