# How to measure "Response Time" in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cycle-time-and-lead-time?view=azure-devops) describe widgets for measuring Lead and Cycle Time.

Is there a way how to measure Response Time (time from Work Item creation until it gets in state In Progress, or Lead Time - Cycle Time)?

I have found [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946837/vsts-incident-management) where there is a statement

> Use queries and analytics to fetch SLA/SLI in PowerBI Dashboard

but I am not sure how to do it .. tried Queries, but did not see at a first glance a possibility to output a calculated/derived column ..

Answer (score 1):

> How to measure “Response Time” in Azure DevOps?

Sorry for the inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such out of box way to output a calculated/derived column about the `Response Time`. That because Azure devops doesn't have an SLA component/feature. Although we can get `Lead Time` and `Cycle Time`, there is such component/feature to get the result for Lead Time - Cycle Time.

As workaround, we could add a custom work item field for tracking the states change of the work items.

Then query the workitems by the custom field, and analytics to fetch date in **PowerBI Dashboard** not the Azure devops dashboard directly.

You could check the document [Connect to Visual Studio Team Services with Power BI](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/powerbi/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.